# AJAX Unique ID div color change per post if user logs in

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

There are many posts that are made by users, I want each post (or div in this case) to display the background color green or grey depending on the user status (logged in or not).
What I am trying to achieve is while idling on the page, you should see a user going online without refreshing the page

**status.php**

```
if (logged_in() === true){  
    $res8 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE status=1 LIMIT 1");
    if(mysql_num_rows($res8) > 0){
        while($row8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res8)){
            if ($row8['status'] === "1") {                  
                echo "online";
            }
        }
    }   
}else {
    echo "offline";
}
```

**Main page**

```
 $res8 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_id='".$user_id."' LIMIT 1");
    if(mysql_num_rows($res8) > 0){
        while($row8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res8)){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function() {
                setInterval(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                      url: 'status.php',
                      datatype:"application/json",
                      type: 'GET',
                      success: function(data) {
                        if (data === "online") {
                        $('.status').css({background: '#40A547'});  
                        } else { 
                        $('.status').css({background: '#7f8c8d'});
                        }
                      }
                    });
                }, 5000);
               });
            </script>
    <?php                       
            }
        }
    }
    echo '<div class="status">TEST</div></a></div>';
```

This code changes the background color of all the divs but I want it to only target the divs that correspond to the user that logged in (the creator of the post).
Not sure how to make the div have the dynamic styling using ajax.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: For that you need to have something unique identifying that user in your HTML.

Comment: you should pass user_id to status.php and send this request for each item separately.

Comment: Show us the HTML code of the posts.

Comment: Also why are you having the same ajax function declared for every user with an interval of 5 seconds?? That's very redundant and not at all necessary. Let the AJAX be out of the PHP. Have it called for 5 seconds to return you all the user_ids online. Change color to green of all those user_ids and the rest can be grey.

Comment: Could you show me in an answer what you mean? I will be able to vote as an answer that way too

Comment: I am imagining it would be a query that checks for all the online users and ajax calls that page. Only thing I am not too sure about is what will the php page return? or how will this look in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the id user from the database to achieve this. Then add an id to the div corresponding to the user id. For instance :

**Ajax Request in success :**

```
$('.status #user'+ dataId).css({background: '#7f8c8d'});
```

**In your HTML :**

```
echo '<div class="status" id="user1">TEST</div></a></div>';
```

## Edit

**Your Main page** (your AJAX request)

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'status.php',
   dataType: "json",
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(data) {
       if (data.message === "online")
       {
           $('.status #user'+ data.userId).css({background: '#40A547'});  
       } else // data.message === "offline"
       { 
           $('.status #user'+ data.userId).css({background: '#7f8c8d'});
       }
   }
});
//...
// HTML looks like...
echo '<div class="status" id="user1">TEST</div></a></div>';
echo '<div class="status" id="user2">TEST2</div></a></div>';
```

**status.php**

You set the `dataType` of your ajax request that you want return Json but it's unclea, your your `status.php` add the header content-type to json.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json'); // So add this
//...
$array = array(); // New variable which would be return as json

if (logged_in() === true) // Your online part
{
    $res8 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE status=1 LIMIT 1");
    if(mysql_num_rows($res8) > 0){
        while($row8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res8)){
            if ($row8['status'] === "1") {                  
                $array['message'] = 'online';
                $array['userId'] = $row8['user_id']; // Here is the userId (adapt following your code)
            }
        }
    }
}// Your offline part
else {
    $array['message'] = 'offline';
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: what would dataId be? I tried var dataId = <?php echo $user_id; ?>; but it didn't work

Comment: I still can't get all users to show a grey div (offline state). any chance you could help me out?

Comment: when the user logs in, everything is great it turns green. when the user logs out, it won't change to grey unless i refresh the page which is not real time. Also, i noticed that if I log in with one user on one browser and another user on another browser, only the latest user is taken into ajax and only that user's post are green instead of both users' post

Comment: In my sample of code I don't re-add your setInterval() which allow you to refresh the ajax request every 5 seconds (following your code in your question). Otherwise maybe your problem is in another place. For instance your `logged_in()` function. Also I see that your request does return only one user (`LIMIT 1`). To finish, if you can change your `mysql_*` functions to `mysqli_*` because these functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5.

Comment: i realized the limit and removed it but it still seems to only take the last user that logs in rather than adding the user id to the array while keeping the old user id's too. and i still have the 5 second function in so that's fine

Comment: My big mistake. I always override the $array in the loop. Set up the identifier to the array as key to make it working. If I'm unclear I update my code tomorrow. I've no computer here.

Comment: Yeah if you dont mind updating your answer that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've got a question. In your select query you have a clause to select all users with status=1. So, all of them are supposed to have a green line (as connected). Last thing, you accept the answer, have you find a way to achieve your problem ?